# how to sum a list i got from database in python. error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for : 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

how to sum elements in a list i got from database in python. each time i am trying i am getting the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

```
def sum_num(mylist):
     return sum(mylist)
```

when i print my list i get this [(52642,), (57127,), (9000,), (29000,), (350000,), (21000,), (41400,), (21600,)] is the data from my table

mylist is a list that was populated from data from my database. can anyone tell me where is there error? if there is any other way to do this?

when i am doing print sum(mylist[1]+ mylist[2]) i am getin the right answer

Comment: Show us what does your mylist contains?

Comment: You probably have a list or rows; have you tried printing `mylist`?

Comment: I bet your list contains tuples and not ints.

Comment: when i print my list i get this [(52642,), (57127,), (9000,), (29000,), (350000,), (21000,), (41400,), (21600,)] is the data from my table

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [ i[0] for i in mylist]
sum(lst)
```

This way requires the creation of another list, but it is an alternative you could also consider.

**Edit:**

Like others mentioned already, the elements of `mylist` are tuples. Since each element in `mylist` has a numerical value (int) in its first position, you sum the values located at position `0` of each of the elements(tuples) inside the list.

Comment: `sum(t[0] for t in mylist)`

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ...this is what i get

Comment: @user2079248 -- the typeError you are getting means that you are trying iterate over an int instead of a list. Are you sure you are iterating over `mylist`? Try to implement what @J.F. Sebastian suggested is more elegant and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of tuples, so you should do something like this:

```
sum( sum(tuple) for tuple in mylist )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can flatten the list of lists or tuples first before summing the components:

```
mylist =  [(52642,), (57127,), (9000,), (29000,), (350000,), (21000,)...]
sum(sum(mylist,()))
```

Comment: i tried this and it says "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: notice the sum(mylist, ()) within the call. the inner sum flattens your list into something like (52642, 57127, 9000, 29000, 350000, 21000, ...) allowing the outer sum to work on the ints.